# Vlc plugin error, No plugins found

Tags: vlc, plugins

I installed **vlc** via ppa from vlc
After some days it started giving plugin errors, I removed vlc and purged the ppa

But still it gives plugin errors whenever I install other software from USC, or I update my machine.

Like:

> main libvlc error: No plugins found! Check your VLC installation.

Screenshots

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would seem you installed vlc* from the videolan master ppa. Ocassionaly it will produce builds that complete but have no plugins, ie. worthless.

If you have synaptic installed or can install, open it up, search vlc & mark ALL the vlc packages for complete removal, there will be 5 or 6

(libvlc5; libvlccore5 ; vlc-data; vlc-nox; vlc-plugin-notify; vlc-plugin-pulse

Alternately try this, removing vlc-data should remove all

```
sudo apt-get purge vlc-data
```

When you get this all cleaned up & if desiring the newly named 1.2, (vlc-2.0), then use this ppa for a stable build, for 11.10 & 12.04 only

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
```

Lp page, - https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/stable-daily

Comment: I'm using 12.04, decided to give the stable ppa a test run today on a fresh install, works fine. Currently a new 32 bit build is queued up, should be done in a few hr's or so. (though the previous would still be available.  Should work fine on 11,10